# Помогите сверстать таблицу HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, мне надо сверстать таблицу но немного не получается, а именно не могу распределить размеры ячеек, вот что надо получить на выходе:

[image]

Вот у меня есть:

[image]

Пожалуйста, помогите правильно оформить размеры ячеек чтобы получилось как на картинке, я в html и css новичок. Вот html - http://pastebin.com/GdkgbNHH , вот css - http://pastebin.com/hQzPCFvi

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте к `<td>F</td>` атрибут `rowspan="2"` чтобы вышло `<td rowspan="2">F</td>` а к J `colspan="3"` чтобы вышло `<td colspan="3">J</td>`, это в HTML

А если нужно чтобы Е имело высоту на половину D тогда добавьте в CSS:

`#tdD1 {height:50%;}`

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо большое))